# Editing default master Broke Central Admin

Tags: 2010, master-page, central-administration

My environment is SharePoint 2010. I was working on some master page changes and accidently I opened default master from (C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\GLOBAL\default.master) in SharePoint designer for some reason it removes the "~/" from the path of following user controls

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="Welcome" src="~/_controltemplates/Welcome.ascx"   %>
    <%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="MUISelector"   src="~/_controltemplates/MUISelector.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="DesignModeConsole" src="~/_controltemplates/DesignModeConsole.ascx" %>.
```

I opened my default master in notepad and corrected the path by adding the tilde and slash but still my master page is not loading properly and i get the "File Not Found error". In view source the error is "/_catalogs/masterpage/_controltemplates/Welcome.ascx does not exist"

Please help.

Best Regards
Vivek

Comment: Even I tried to reset the master page back to site definition but it didn't help either.

Comment: can you configure the web.config to display the detailed error? Make - `<CustomErrors Mode="Off">`, `CallStack="true"` and `<compilation debug="true" />` and then refresh the site.

Comment: yes i have these settings.it shows me error that welcome.acsx doesn't exist though its present physically.

Comment: you wouldn't by any chance have the publishing feature enabled and be able to restore an earlier version? Also you mention you're working on a 2010 install, I would have thought that you would have been working with v4.master

Comment: Well I think default.master should be the culprit as all this started after opening it in SPD

Answer (score 1):

You have another copy of default.master under C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\Layouts\

Both files should be exactly the same, so copy the good one over the broken one.

Comment: Unfortunately this also dint work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Reset to site definition option under Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Site Actions..
This will reset your site with default settings..

Comment: I did this but of no use.

Comment: This would only reset it to the file definition.. which is broken.